# SqlCacheDepency.. QueryNotification subscription not working

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

```
 public class MemoryCacheHelper
{
    private static string _conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EFMultiPoolDbContext"] != null ?
       ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EFMultiPoolDbContext"].ConnectionString :
       ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EFDbContext"].ConnectionString;

    private static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    private static int _hourOfExpiry = 8; // ConfigurationHelper.GetValue<int>("Cache:HourExpiry", 8);

    //private static SqlDependency dependency;
    private static ObjectCache _cache = MemoryCache.Default;
    private static WebCaching.Cache _webcache = new WebCaching.Cache();

    private ReaderWriterLockSlim _cachelock = null;

    public MemoryCacheHelper()
    {
        _cachelock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
        EnoughPermission();
    }

    public void Add(string key, object val)
    {
        Add(key, val, new CacheItemPolicy()
        {
            SlidingExpiration = new TimeSpan(_hourOfExpiry, 0, 0)
        });
    }

    public void Add(string key, object val, int seconds)
    {
        Add(key, val, new CacheItemPolicy()
        {
            //SlidingExpiration = new TimeSpan(0,0,seconds)
            AbsoluteExpiration = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(seconds))
        });
    }


    public void Add(string key, object val, int mins, WebCaching.CacheDependency dependency)
    {
        if (val == null)
            return;

        //_cachelock.EnterReadLock();

        try
        {
            //if (_cache1.Get(key) != null)
            {
                _logger.Debug(string.Format("Cache Key: {0} set at {1}", key, DateTime.Now));
                _webcache.Insert(key, val, dependency, WebCaching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(mins),
                    WebCaching.CacheItemPriority.Default, CacheItemRemovedCallback);
                //if (key == "productTypes")
                // _logger.Debug(string.Format("Cache Key: {0} set at {1}", key, DateTime.Now));
            }

        }
        finally
        {
            // _cachelock.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }



    public static T CheckOrRequeryWebCache<T>(string key, int mins, string commandText)
    {
        var cache = new MemoryCacheHelper();
        object res = cache.GetWebCacheItem(key);

        if (res == null)
        {
            SqlDependency.Stop(_conn);
            SqlDependency.Start(_conn);

            using (var con = new SqlConnection(_conn))
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {

                    con.Open();
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.Notification = null;
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                    cmd.CommandText=@"SET ANSI_NULLS ON;SET ANSI_PADDING ON;SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON;SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF;SET ARITHABORT ON;";
                    {
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    cmd.CommandText = commandText;

                    var ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds);

                    if (key == "visualIdPLUs")
                        res = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(x => Convert.ToString(x["ParentPLU"])).ToList();
                    else
                        res = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(x => new BlockedGIdDateExchangePLU
                        {
                            PLU = Convert.ToString(x["ParentPLU"]),
                            CanExchangeDate = Convert.ToBoolean(x["CanExchangeDate"]),
                            CanExchangeGId = Convert.ToBoolean(x["CanExchangeGId"])
                        }).ToList();

                    var dependency = new WebCaching.SqlCacheDependency(cmd);

                    //dependency = new SqlDependency(cmd);
                    //dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                    cache.Add(key, res, mins, dependency);
                }
            }
        }
        return (T)res;

    }

    private static void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private bool EnoughPermission()
    {
        SqlClientPermission perm = new SqlClientPermission(System.Security.Permissions.PermissionState.Unrestricted);
        try
        {
            perm.Demand();
            return true;
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

[profiler trace for working sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIYJn.jpg)   [profiler trace for my main project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dON3C.jpg)Am working on SqlCacheDependency. i need to implement it in my main project

in order to test first , i have created sample MVC project and implemented is working perfectly fine, can see all the QueryNotification events on profiler.

when am trying to run the same code in my main project is not working.. the problem i found out from sql profiler is not all qn events are firing.. starting from susbscription event.

can anyone please suggest what is wrong.. (note: am using same database and sql login for both sample and main project)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please edit these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: HI, Am trying to work with SqlQueryNotifications and SqlCacheDependency, the above code succesfully able to create a sqlnotification service in SqlServer.. but my application for some unknown reason unable to subscribe to QueryNotification the same code works perfectly in a sample mvc app.. have attached sql profiler trace for both working and non-working version , the working sql trace shows a bunch of QN events those events are absent in the other image, hence the notifications are not working and cache object not updated